# Pointing to new files -- Gulp

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, gulp

I am using Gulp with a laravel project.

For example, I have a `js` folder with all the javascript files in it and I have created a *bundle* js file from them.

I am unable to understand how to tell my project that "this" is the "new" file that you have to use?

Every online resource tells me how to bundle them, how to watch them, but I 
couldn't find this anywhere.

Comment: Give link to bundle.js file in your html file

Comment: let us say actually, we have two js files foo.js and bar.js in our js folder and we have merged them to get bundle.js. So now, in our project, we would still have two lines like these <script src="/master/foo.js"></script> somewhere in the code right ? So how does the project know that it has to use the new bundle.js file ?

Comment: remove foo.js and bar.js in your html code. keep only bundle.js file.

Comment: so wherever we have minified our files, there we have to "manually" add the bundle files , deleting the old ones ?

Comment: no. gulp will take care of that task. you just use your bundle.js and just refresh browser'

Comment: So, I don't have to remove foo.js and bar.js from the code ?

Comment: You should remove the foo.js and bar.js from code. and keep only build.js. dot

Comment: So, say I have ten files which has 4-5 scripts included in each of them. What you are saying is bundle all the js files from all my ten files and in every one of those ten files remove all js scripts and just add bundle.js ?

Comment: Yes. Thats why your are bundling.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that we are including all the js dependencies everywhere, even where we don't need them ?

Comment: Yes. To avoid that we have lazyloading js files. Google it.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a "real" code question but an overall confusion at the concept of bundling and also how `gulp` works. you are basically asking people to teach you things which are written in countless tutorials on the web

Comment: All the tutorials say how to bundle the files, how to watch the files etc,etc but not how the bundle is loaded into our project. I will be grateful if you point me to one tutorial.